# Access sequence element from fasta record using Biopython Entrez

Tags: python, biopython, fasta, ncbi

I have a list of refseq IDs (keys_list) that I'm using to pull down sequence records using BioPython Entrez. I'd like to access just the sequence from fasta records returned, but I don't want to have to write the records to file to do so.

I'm trying the foloowing code

```
for key in key_list:
   Entrez.email = "myemailaddress"
   handle = Entrez.efetch(db='nuccore', id=key, rettype='fasta')
   record = SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta")
   for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(record, "fasta"):
    print seq_record.seq
```

When I run this I'm getting the error:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/__init__.py", line 538, in parse
  yield r
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/contextlib.py", line 34, in __exit__
  self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Bio/File.py", line 59, in as_handle
  yield handleish
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/__init__.py", line 537, in parse
  for r in i:
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/FastaIO.py", line 37, in FastaIterator
  line = handle.readline()
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'readline'
```

If I return the entire record with `handle.read()`, I can get the whole fasta record, but at this stage I'd just like to access the nucleotide sequence only.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need.

Instead of:

```
handle = Entrez.efetch(db='nuccore', id=key, rettype='fasta')
```

Try this:

```
handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id=key, retmode="xml") # retmode as 'xml' , db='nucleotide'
features = Entrez.read(handle)[0]
sequence = features['GBSeq_sequence'] # this is your sequence!
```

Which returns a character string that is your sequence:

```
'ggctcgcatctctccttcacgcgcccgccgccttacctgaggccgccatccacgccggttgagtcgcgttctgccgcctcccgcctgtggtgcctcctgaactacgtccgccgtctaggtaagtttagagctcaggtcgagaccgggcctttgtccggcgctcccttggagcctacctagactcagccggctctccacgctttgcctgaccctgcttgctcaactctacgtctttgtttcgttttctgttctgcgccgttacagatcgaaagttccacccctttccctttcattcacgactgactgccggcttggcccacggccaagtaccggcaactctgctggctcggagccagcgacagcccattctatagcactctccaggagagaaatttagtacacagttgggggctcgtccgggattcgagcgcccctttattccctaggcaatgggccaaatcttttcccgtagcgctagccctattccgcggccgccccgggggctggccgctcatcactggcttaacttcctccaggcggcatatcgcctagaacccggtccctccagttacgatttccaccagttaaaaaaatttcttaaaatagctttagaaacaccggtctggatctgccccattaactactccctcctagccagcctactcccaaaaggataccccggccgggtgaatgaaattttacacatactcatccaaacccaagcccagatcccgtcccgccccgcgccgccgccgccgtcatcctccacccacgaccccccggattctgacccacaaatcccccctccctatgttgagcctacagccccccaagtccttccagtcatgcacccacatggtgcccctcccaaccaccgcccatggcaaatgaaagacctacaggccattaagcaagaagtctcccaagcggcccctggaagcccccagtttatgcagaccatccggcttgcggtgcagcagtttgaccccactgccaaagacctccaagacctcctgcagtacctttgctcctccctcgtggcttccctccatcaccagcagctagatagccttatatcagaggccgaaactcgaggtattacaggttataaccccttagccggtcccctccgtgtccaagccaacaatccacaacaacaaggattaaggcgagaataccagcaactctggctcgccgccttcgccgccctgccagggagtgccaaagacccttcctgggcctctatcctccaaggcctggaggagccttaccacgccttcgtagaacgcctcaacatagctcttgacaatgggctgccagaaggcacgcccaaagaccccattttacgttccttagcctactctaatgcaaacaaagaatgccaaaaattactacaggcccgagggcacactaatagccctctaggagatatgttgcgggcttgtcaggcctggacccccaaagacaaaaccaaagtgttagttgtccagcctaaaaaaccccccccaaatcagccgtgcttccggtgcgggaaagcaggccactggagtcgggactgcactcagcctcgtcctccccctgggccatgccccctatgtcaagatccaactcactggaagcgagactgcccccgcctaaagcccactatcccagaaccagagccagaggaggatgccctcctattagatctccccgccgacatcccacacccaaaaaactccatagggggggaggtttaacctccccccccacattacagcaagtccttcctaaccaagacccaacatctattctgccagttataccgttagatcccgcccgtcggcccgtaattaaagcccagattgacacccagaccagccacccaaagactatcgaagctctactagatacaggagcagacatgacagtccttccgatagccttgttctcaagtaatactcccctcaaaaacacatccgtgttaggggcagggggccaaacccaagatcactttaagctcacctcccttcctgtgctaatacgcctccctttccggacgacgcctattgttttaacatcttgcctagttgataccaaaaacaactgggccatcataggtcgtgatgccttacaacaatgccaaggcgtcctgtacctccctgaggcaaaaaggccgcctgtaatcttgccaatacaggcgccagctgtccttgggctagaacacctcccaaggccccccgaaatcagccagttccctttaaaccagaacgcctccaggccttgcaacacttggtccggaaggccctggaggcaggccatatcgaaccctacaccgggccaggaaataacccagtattcccagttaaaaaagccaatggaacctggcgattcatccacgacctgcgggccactaactctctaaccatagatctctcatcatcttcccccgggccccctgacttgtccagcctgccaactacactagcccacttacaaactatagaccttaaagacgcctttttccaaatccccctacctaaacagttccagccctactttgctttcactgtcccacagcagtgtaactacggccccggcactagatacgcctggagagtactaccccaagggtttaaaaatagtcccaccctgttcgaaatgcagctggcccatatcctgcagcccattcggcaagccttcccccaatgcactattcttcagtacatggatgacattctcctggcaagcccctcccatgcggacctgcaactactctcagaggccacaatggcttccctaatctcccatgggttgcctgtgtccgaaaacaaaacccagcaaacccctggaacaattaagttcctagggcaaataatttcacctaatcacctcacttatgatgcagtccccaaggtacctatacggtcccgctgggcgctacctgaacttcaagccctacttggcgagattcagtgggtctccaaaggaactcctaccttacgccagccccttcacagtctctactgtgccttacaaaggcatactgatccccgagaccaaatatatttaaatccttctcaagttcaatcattagtgcagctgcggcaggccctgtcacagaactgccgcagtagactagtccaaaccctgcccctcctaggggctattatgctgaccctcactggcaccaccactgtggtgttccagtccaagcagcagtggccacttgtctggctacatgcccccctaccccacactagccagtgcccctgggggcagctacttgcctcagctgtgttattactcgacaaatacaccttgcaatcctatggactactctgccaaaccatacatcataacatctccacccaaaccttcaaccaattcattcaaacatctgaccaccccagtgttcctatcttactccaccacagtcaccgattcaaaaatttaggtgcccagactggagaactttggaacacttttcttaaaacaactgccccattggctcctgtgaaagcccttatgccagtgtttactctttcccctgtgatcataaacaccgccccttgcctgttttcagacggatccacctcccaggcagcctatattctctgggacaagcatatattgtcacaaagatcattcccccttccgccaccgcacaagtcggcccaacgggccgaacttctcggacttttgcatggcctctccagcgcccgttcgtggcgctgtctcaacatatttctagactccaagtatctttatcattaccttcggacccttgccctaggcaccttccaaggcaggtcctctcaggccccctttcaggccctcctgccccgcttactatcgcgtaaggtcgtctatttgcaccacgttcgcagccataccaatctacctgatcccatctccaggctcaacgctctcacagatgccctactaatcacccctgtcctgcagctctctcctgcagacctacacagtttcacccattgcggacagacggccctcacactgcaaggggcaaccacaactgaggcctccaatatcctgcgctcttgccacgcctgccgcaaaaataacccacaacatcagatgcctcaaggacacatccgccgtggcctactccctaaccacatctggcaaggcgacattacccatttcaaatataaaaatacactgtatcgccttcatgtatgggtagacaccttttcaggagccatctcagctacccaaaagagaaaagaaacaagctcagaagctatttcctctttgctccaggccattgcctatctaggcaagcctagctacataaacacagacaatggccctgcctatatttcccaagacttcctcaatatgtgtacctcccttgctattcgccatactacccatgtcccctacaatccaaccagctccggacttgtagaacgctctaatggcattcttaaaaccctattatataagtactttactgacaaacccgacctacctatggataatgctctatccatagccctatggacaatcaaccacctaaatgtattaaccaactgccacaaaacccgatggcagcttcaccactccccccgactccagccgatcccagagacacattccctcagcaataaacaaacccattggtattatttcaagcttcctggtcttaatagccgccagtggaaaggaccacaggaggctcttcaagaagctgccggcgctgctctcatcccggtaagcgctagttctgcccagtggatcccgtggaggctcctcaagcgagctgcatgcccaagacccgtcggaggccccgccgatcccaaagaaaaagaccaccaacaccatgggtaagtttctcgccactttgattttattcttccagttctgccccctcatcctcggtgattacagccccagctgctgtactctcacagttggagtctcctcataccactctaaaccctgcaatcctgcccagccagtttgttcatggaccctcgacctgctggccctttcagcagatcaggccctacagccaccctgccctaatctagtaagttactccagctaccatgccacctattccctatatctattccctcattggatcaaaaagccaaaccgaaatggcggaggctattattcagcctcttattcagacccttgttccttaaaatgcccatacctagggtgccaatcatggacctgcccctatacaggagccgtctccagcccctactggaaatttcagcaagatgtcaattttactcaagaagtttcacacctcaatattaatctccatttttcaaaatgcggtttttccttctcccttctagtcgacgctccaggatatgaccccatctggttccttaataccgaacccagccaactgcctcccaccgcccctcctctactctcccactctaacctagaccatatcctcgagccctctataccatggaaatcaaaactcctgactcttgtccagttaaccctacaaagcactaattatacttgcattgtctgtatcgatcgtgccagcctatccacttggcacgtcctatactctcccaacgtctctgttccatccccttcttctacccccctcctttacccatcgttagcgcttccagccccccacctgacgttaccatttaactggacccactgctttgacccccagattcaagctatagtctcctccccctgtcataactccctcatcctgccccccttttccttgtcacctgttcccacgctaggatcccgctcccgccgagcagtaccggtggcggtctggcttgtctccgccctggccatgggagccggagtggctggcaggattaccggctccatgtccctcgcctcaggaaagagcctcctacatgaggtggacaaagatatttcccaattaactcaagcaatagtcaaaaaccacaaaaatctgctcaaaattgcacagtatgctgcccagaacagacgaggccttgatctcctgttctgggagcaaggaggattatgcaaagcattacaagaacagtgctgttttctaaatattactaattcccatgtctcaatactacaagagagacccccccttgaaaatcgagtcctgactggctggggccttaactgggaccttggcctctcacagtgggctcgagaagccttacaaactggaatcacccttgtcgcgctactccttcttgttatccttgcaggaccatgcatcctccgtcagctacgacacctcccctcgcgcgtcagatacccccattactctcttataaaccctgagtcatccctgtaaaccaagcacacaattattgcaaccacatcgcctccagcctcccctgccaataattaacctctcccatcaaatcctccttctcctgcagcaacctcctccgttcagcctccaaggactccacctcgccttccaactgtctagtatagccatcaacccccaactcctgcattttttctttcctagcactatgctgtttcgccttctcagccccttgtctccacttgcgctcacggcgctcctgctcttcctgctttctccgggcgaagtcagcggccttctcctccgcccgcttcctgcgccgtgccttctcctcttccttccttttcaaatactcagcaatctgcttttcctcctctttctcccgctctttttttcgcttcctcttctcctcagcccgtcgctgccgatcacgatgcgtttccccgcgaggtggcgctttcccccctggagggccccgtcgcagccggccgcggctttcctcttctagagatagcaaaccgtcaagcacagtttcctcctcctccttgtcctttaactcttcctccaaggataatagcccgtccaccaattcctccaccagcaggtcctccgggcatggaacaggcaaacatcgaaacagccctacggatacaaagttaaccatgcttattatcagcccacttcccagggtttggacagagtcttcttttcggatacccagtctacgtgtttggagactgtgtacaaggcgactggtgccccatctctgggggactatgttcggcccgcctacatcgtcacgccctactggccacctgtccagagcatcagatcacctgggaccccatcgatggacgcgttatcggctcagctctacagttccttatccctcgactcccctccttccccacccagagaacctctaagacccttaaggtccttaccccgccaatcactcatacaacccccaacattccaccctccttcctccaggccatgcgcaaatactcccccttccgaaatggatacatggaacccacccttgggcagcacctcccaaccctgtcttttccagaccccggactccggccccaaaacctgtacaccctctggggaggctccgttgtctgcatgtacctctaccagctttccccccccatcacctggcccctcctgccccatgtgattttttgccaccccggccagctcggggccttcctcaccaatgttccctacaaacgaatagaaaaactcctctataaaatttcccttaccacaggggccctaataattctacccgaggactgtttgcccaccacccttttccagcctgctagggcacccgtcacgctgacagcctggcaaaacggcctccttccgttccactcaaccctcaccactccaggccttatttggacatttaccgatggcacgcctatgatttccgggccctgccctaaagatggccagccatctttagtactacagtcctcctcctttatatttcacaaatttcaaaccaaggcctaccacccctcatttctactctcacacggcctcatacagtactcttcctttcataatttgcatctcctatttgaagaatacaccaacatccccatttctctactttttaacgaaaaagaggcagatgacaatgaccatgagccccaaatatcccccgggggcttagagcctctcagtgaaaaacatttccgtgaaacagaagtctgagaaggtcagggcccagaataaggctctgacgtctccccccggaggacagctcagcaccagctcaggctaggccctgacgtgtccccctaaagacaaatcataagctcagacctccgggaagccaccgggaaccacccatttcctccccatgtttgtcaagccgtcctcaggcgttgacgacaacccctcacctcaaaaaacttttcatggcacgcatacggctcaataaaataacaggagtctataaaagcgtggggacagttcaggagggggctcgcatctctccttcacgcgcccgccgccttacctgaggccgccatccacgccggttgagtcgcgttctgccgcctcccgcctgtggtgcctcctgaactacgtccgccgtctaggtaagtttagagctcaggtcgagaccgggcctttgtccggcgctcccttggagcctacctagactcagccggctctccacgctttgcctgaccctgcttgctcaactcta'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that when you use biopython to parse the fasta file, it organizes the information into a dictionary of dictionaries.  You can check how everything is organized yourself by printing

```
print dir(seq_record)
```

I know that when parsing a genbank file, each seq_record has a dictionary called features, so for a FASTA file, assuming it is organized the same way you can access just the sequence by the following

```
for record in SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta"):
    for f in record.features:
        print "sequence"
        print dir(f) # Print the attributes of f to make sure that "sequence" used in the above line is in fact a key in the dictionary, if not pick the correct key to use above
```